# pattern::op::Or on last layer openvino

Tags: c++, openvino

I'm working which a model which needs some replacements. For this I'm using openvino matcher. I wrote the replacement pattern as needed by openvino but I have conditional last layers

e.g. I could have a Add or a Relu at the end and I can't seem to find the pattern using

```
auto add = pattern::wrap_type<opset6::Add>({ mulLeft, sub });
auto relu = pattern::wrap_type<opset6::Relu>({ add });
auto reluOrAdd = std::make_shared<pattern::op::Or>(OutputVector{relu, add})
```

The problem is that this returns me add all the time even if relu is present

I am new to this world so If I'm missing any other op which should be used, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The ReLu operation needs to be registered as a new node by implementing callback mechanism. Refer to [Implement Callback](https://docs.openvino.ai/nightly/openvino_docs_Extensibility_UG_matcher_pass.html#implement-callback) for example of using MatcherPass to fuse sequence of operations using the register_new_node method.